# ContextMenu - Strange behavior when using ItemContainerStyle

Tags: wpf, xaml, contextmenu, itemcontainerstyle

I'm having a strange issue with my `ContextMenu`. The `ItemsSource` is a `List<Layer> Layers;`, where the `Layer` class overrides the `ToString()` to return the `Name` property.

If I don't use any `ItemContainerStyle` for the context menu, it all works fine - it takes the `Layer` object and displays the `ToString()` of that object, like it should. When I add the `ItemContainerStyle`, it shows an empty string.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="myItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Border SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Height="32" Width="200" Background="White">
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Background="{x:Null}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF3B3D52"
                                   Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>


<Button ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="False">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu FontFamily="Global Sans Serif" Height="Auto" Width="200" Padding="0,6" VerticalOffset="5" BorderThickness="0" 
                     HasDropShadow="True" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource myItemControlTemplate}">
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

And here's how I fire it:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;

    ContextMenu ctm = btn.ContextMenu;
    ctm.ItemsSource = Layers;
    ctm.PlacementTarget = btn;
    ctm.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
    ctm.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Could it be that for some reason this binding gets busted somehow?

```
Text="{TemplateBinding Header}"
```

BTW, if I change the layers list to be a `List<string>` and just feed it the names of the layers, it works correctly with the `ItemContainerStyle`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the [`TemplateBinding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). This is a less powerful but optimized variant of a relative source binding to a templated parent, but it comes at the expense of several limitations, like not supporting two-way binding. Although not officially stated in the documentation, it seems that this binding does not support conversion of the underlying type to `string`, as `ToString` is never called in this case.

Replace the `TemplateBinding` with a binding to the templated parent using relative source.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap"
           Text="{Binding Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF3B3D52"
           Grid.Column="1" Margin="6,0,0,0"/>
```

Comment: Learn something everyday! Thanks for the explanation. Cheers.